# Difference between fbeta_score and precision_recall_fscore_support when used with GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to set the scoring function for GridSearchCV in scikit-learn for a multiclass classification problem.

My question is that what is the difference between `fbeta_score` and `precision_recall_fscore_support`?

[According to the documentation,](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support) `precision_recall_fscore_support` returns more than one value. GridSearchCV use which value/score? Does it designed to be used with GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `precision_recall_fscore_support` is a sort of "summary" function, which caluclates 4 different metrics. This is not intended to be used directly as a scorer function, since a scorer function needs to have only a scalar output value. Three of these components of `precision_recall_fscore_support` can be used with the `score` paramater in `GridSearchCV`, in the form: `precision_score`, `recall_score` and `fbeta_score`.